# eloquent query multiple relations deep

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 3 models in question. Company, User, Group. I am trying to return all company records whose creator (user) has a (group) of what I specify.

Company.php

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

User.php

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Company')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}

public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Group')->withTimestamps();
}

public function hasGroup($check)
{
    if(is_array($check)) {
        $groups = array_fetch($this->group->toArray(), 'name_short');
        return !!array_intersect($check, $groups) ? true : false;
    } else {
        return in_array($check, array_fetch($this->group->toArray(), 'name_short'));
    }
}
```

Group.php

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');    
}
```

I know how to query immediately related models. Not sure where to start on models related to immediately related models.

The following is just a concept, not workable code. Just how I would think it would work.

```
$companies = Company::where('active','=','1')where($this->user->hasGroup(array('admin','moderator','subscriber')));
```

This kind of gets me what I am looking for.

```
$c = Company::with('user.group')->where('active','=',1)->get();
```

It kinda shows what I need, just don't know how to only show records with a certain company->user->group ownership. Here is an output of this in JSON for readability - http://pastebin.com/wFTi9ye0

Tried this, doesnt work:

```
$names = array('subscriber','user');
$c = Company::with(array('user.group' => function($query) use($names)
{
    $query->whereIn('name_short', $names)
}))->get();
```

.edit.
Just tried this:

```
$c = Company::whereHas('user', function($q)
{
    $q->whereHas('group', function($q)
    {
        $q->where('name_short', '=', 'user');
    });
});

#print_r($c->toJSON());
print_r($c);
```

Browser crashed. I feel I am close. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out :)

```
$c = Company::where('active','=',1)->whereHas('user', function($q)
{
    $q->whereHas('group', function($q)
    {
        $q->whereIn('group.name_short', array('admin','user'));
    });
})->get();
```